# AttributeError: module 'tfx.utils.io_utils' has no attribute 'file_io'

Tags: tfx

I updated the tfx from 0.22.0 to 1.8.0 and now I'm getting this error:

```
AttributeError: module 'tfx.utils.io_utils' has no attribute 'file_io'
```

The code is:

```
from tfx.utils import io_utils

io_utils.file_io.read_file_to_string(fname)
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to call `io_utils.file_io.read_file_to_string` in tfx version 1.8.0 is:

```
from tfx.utils import io_utils
io_utils.read_string_file(fname)
```